# Terraform KeyVault Secrets (Error Already Exist)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform template but instead of having multiple steps for each secret I have created a loop

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "keyvaultsecrets" {
  for_each     = local.secrets
  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.price_keyvault.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc
  ]
}
```

However, when I run this template twice I get the error stating the secret already exists. Is this because the step name, in this case `keyvaultsecrets` is in the state file? Is this better done as separate steps like:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret1" {
  name         = "secret1"
  value        = "foobar"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.price_keyvault.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret2" {
  name         = "secret2"
  value        = "oooh"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.price_keyvault.id
}
```

Comment: What is `local.secrets`?

Comment: Especially - are you sure the `local.secrets` has only two elements, not more?

Comment: can you share the structure of local. Secrets?

Comment: Which azurerm version are you using in provider.tf? For example, with 3.31.0 you get this error but with 3.47.0 don't

Answer (score 0):

If the secret already exists, you will need to import it into state:

`terraform import azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyvaultsecrets["<key>"] "<full key vault id path, should be in your error>"`

If you're using PowerShell, you'll have to escape the double quotes around the .